# Facebook sandbox app whitescreen

Tags: facebook

I've just set up a new app on Facebook, provided the bare minimal details:

- name
- namespace
- canvas url

Set it to sandbox mode and went to the app's namespace. All I get though is a white screen and a popup about secure/insecure content.

Am I right in thinking you *don't* need an SSL-enabled web server if your app is in sandbox mode?

Also, when I inspect the FB app iframe I can see my local url buried inside and when I manually go to my local URL the app loads (so not an issue at my side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue, Firefox was blocking mixed HTTP + HTTPS content.

Here's some information: https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/

Fix was to click the shield icon in the address bar and allow the security exception